# Can't use Python console on Gedit

Tags: python, gedit

The error message is: Plugin loader python3 was not found

Python3 is installed...

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe gedit functions via plugins to highlight and console for different languages.

From a quick google search, I found a gedit [bug](https://github.com/gmate/gmate/issues/153) with this comment:

'in /usr/lib/gedit/plugin choice your plugin

for example gemini.plugin

Change

[Plugin]
Loader = python

by

[Plugin]
Loader = python3

In some plugins it worked for me'

Comment: I had found this one too. it didn't work for me. The output error is: Plugin loader python was not found

Comment: @Vitor sad. Use gvim?

Comment: Never tried... is it good?

Comment: Yeah, and it's configurable so you can keep the same key bindings you've learned elsewhere, or you can learn gvim's bindings. It's basically vim with a mouse. I like it because I frequently have to open GB-sized log files, which made Gedit *super* laggy on startup. It's not necessarily as pretty as Gedit, but it *always* works.

Comment: Just remember when you start using it that if you think something is missing, it's probably just a plugin you need, or a config file to edit. It's pretty easy and stable, the two most important things for me in a text editor.